# Firebase query join. Help needed

Tags: javascript, sql, firebase

Just started with Firebase and loving it. 
Was watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idu9EJPSxiY and wanted some help with a particular query. If anyone can help?

In the schema/structure below if i wanted to query all the events that a person named "David" attended, what would it be?

```
{
    "users": {
        "key1": {
            "name": "David",
            "age": 33,
            "profileImg": "http/......"
        }
        "key2": {
            "name": "John",
            "age": 25,
            "profileImg": "http/......"
        }
    },
    "events": {
        "fm": {
            "name": "event1",
            "date": 12332443456
        }
    },
    "eventAttendees": {
        "fm": {
            "key1": "David",
            "key2": "John"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm kinda stuck and would like some help. Thanks.
[DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzUvL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (I'm using node.js firebase module to show the example)

```
firebase.database().ref('eventAttendees').once('value', function (eventAttendeesList) {
    var events = []; //array to store the events
    eventAttendeesList.forEach(function (eachEvent) { //forEach list of eventAttendees node, Eg: fm
        eachEvent.forEach(function (data) { //forEach value of current eventAttendees, Eg: jey1: "David", key2: "John"
            if (data.val() == "David") {
                firebase.database().ref('events').child(eachEvent.key).once('value', function (snapshot) { // get the event data
                    events.push(snapshot) // add to array of events David attended
                })
            } //end of if
        })// end of eachEvent.forEach
    })// end of eventAttendeesList.forEach
    return events;
})
```

I might have some syntax error somewhere, but you get the idea

1. First is to query for the list of data under the **eventAttendees** node ("fm") and loop through each value
2. In each of your value for the eventAttendees node there are your key1, key2 which we need to do another loop to get the data ("David", "John"). Here we will check if the data matches the person you are looking for
3. If it matches we will query firebase for the event data under the events node with the key that matches `eachEvent.key` and add it to our events array

Comment: Yeah that works. But let's say if there are 10000s of eventAttendees nodes then wouldn't it be a very expensive operation? Not to forget that you'll be downloading huge megs of data. The docs and the youtube tutorial made it seem like this way of structuring the data would help such multiple join queries. Am i missing something? Thanks for the quick response btw.